# Favicon does not shows up in google chrome

Tags: html, favicon

I have a website which i tested on 3 browsers IE,Firefox and Chrome, my favicon doesn't seems to show up in chrome but it does shows in other browsers. I have tried clearing cache of chrome multiple times but doesn't seems to be helping though.

Can you please suggest me some way to fix this .

Comment: Does it appear in incognito? Favicons are strange when it comes to caching them :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your icon url in new tab and press `ctrl + F5`

To get icon url go to view-source by `ctrl + U` and you well get href click on that url.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=6cd6089ee7f6">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any `body`-related markup (eg. a `div`) in your `head`, before the favicon declarations. For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <div>stuff</div> <?-- This div has nothing to do here -->
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

The reason is: as soon as Chrome encounters a markup it is not supposed to find in the header (`div`, `p`...), it considers the header to be over. Therefore, all following markups, which do not make any sense in the body, are ignored. This is the case of the `link` markup you probably use for the favicon.

This behavior is specific to Chrome. That would explain why you get this bug only with this browser.